# Play! framework. template "include"

Tags: java, scala, web, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

I'm planning my website structure as following:

> - header.scala.html
> - XXX
> - footer.scala.html

now, instead of "xxx" there should be a specific page (i.e. "UsersView.scala.html").
what I need is to include (like with well-known languages) the source of the footer and the 
header into the the middle page's code.

**so my questions are:**

1. How do you include a page in another with scala templating?
2. Do you think it's a good paradigm for Play! framework based website?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A common pattern is to create a template that contains the boilerplate, and takes a parameter of type HTML.  Let's say:

main.scala.html

```
@(content: HTML)

@header
// boilerplate

@content

// more boilerplate
@footer
```

In fact, you don't really need to separate out header and footer with this approach.

Your UsersView.scala.html then looks like this:

```
@main {

// all your users page html here.

}
```

You're wrapping the UsersView with main by passing it in as a parameter.

You can see examples of this in the [samples](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples)

My usual main template is a little more involved and looks roughly like this:

```
@(title: String)(headInsert: Html = Html.empty)(content: Html)(implicit user: Option[User] = None)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>@title</title>
  // bootstrap stuff here
  @headInsert
</head>
<body>
  @menu(user)
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container">  
    @content
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This way a template can pass in a head insert and title, and make a user available, as well as content of course.

Comment: how do you handle the case where a page needs to add additional script and stylesheet tags to the HEAD?

Comment: In the final example, see the headInsert parameter?  You can pass in HTML to be inserted into head using that.  You'd call it something like:  @main("title"){ <script /><link /> }{ ...content... }

Answer (score 33):

Just call another template like a method. If you want to include **footer.scala.html**:

`@footer()`

Answer (score 2):

Play provide a very convenient way to help implement that!

Layout part from official docs:

First we have a base.html (that's we call in django -_-)

```
// views/main.scala.html
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="content">@content</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to use the base.html?

```
@main(title = "Home") {

  <h1>Home page</h1>

}
```

More information [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplateUseCases)